# VIM: swap two columns separated by space

Tags: vim

I have two columns:

```
cats dog  
dog cats
```

I want to swap the two columns:

```
dog cats
cats dog
```

Using vim how would i do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

My first idea, a substitution, ended up looking too much like Birei's so I went with [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) (that I don't know very much) used as a filter:

```
:%!awk '{print $2, $1}'
```

Comment: your solution works, i don't know why someone voted down

Comment: @c4f4t0r, yeah… 1. It works. 2. It's shorter than a substitution. 3. It's very "vimm-y" and "unix-y" as in it uses another specialized program as a filter… Whatever.

Comment: What if the user is on a system which does not has AWK?

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai, apparently the person who asked the question is on a system that has AWK. If you don't you use a substitution or you install proper unix tools.

Comment: How about columns separated by tabs?

Comment: @PratikKhadloya, you read `$ man awk` and figure out how to deal with tabs.

Comment: while this solution works, it is not a very good answer for a question expressly asking how to do this in vim.

Comment: I'm using this approach to swap the columns in a Markdown table. Awk's `-F` flag lets you specify the separator: `:'<,'>!awk -F\| '{print "\|", $4, "\|", $2, "\|", $3}'`

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve it with a regular expression using `\S` for non-blank characters and `\s` for blanks, like:

```
:%s/\v^(\S+)\s+(\S+).*$/\2 \1/
```

It yields:

```
dog cats
cats dog
```

Comment: In case anyone else needs to swap the first column to be the last when there are more than two columns: (dogs ferrets cats -> cats ferrets dogs)
`:%s/\v^(\S+)\s+(\S+)(.*)$/\2\3\ \1/`

Answer (score 2):

You can archive this in this easy way, any caracters in first and second column

```
 :%s/\(.\+\)\(\s\+\)\(.\+\)/\3\2\1/g
```

Answer (score 2):

Following macro can be used:

```
qaqqadf A <esc>pj0q99@a
```

1. `qaq` clears the register a.
2. `qa` start recording macro in register a.
3. `df` delete till the space
4. `A` append after the end of line and give a space
5. `<esc>p` go to normal mode and paste.
6. `j0` go to the first column in next line.
7. `q` stop macro a
8. 99@a  run this macro 99 times (assuming you have 99 columns left)

Answer (score 2):

## «Swap two columns» plugin

Yep, there is such a thing as a [swap two columns](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3708) Vim plugin.

```
        111  222  333  444  555        333  222  111  444  555
        111  222  333  444  555        333  222  111  444  555
        111  222  333  444  555    →   333  222  111  444  555
        111  222  333  444  555        333  222  111  444  555
        111  222  333  444  555        333  222  111  444  555
```

Answer (score 1):

If the columns take the whole file use this:

```
:%normal "adt xA <CTRL-v><CTRL-r>a
```

If it's only a section of the file, make a visual selection end use this:

```
:'<,'>normal "adt xA <CTRL-v><CTRL-r>a
```

Explanation:

- `%`or `'<,'>`: Run the following command on the whole file (`%`) or in a specific section (`'<,'>`);
- `"adt`: Deletes everything until the first space (space not included) and stores the deleted text in the register `a`.
- `x`: deletes the trailing space;
- `A`: starts to append text;
- `<CTRL-v><CTRL-R>a`: Enters the `<CTRL-r>` command (it will show a `^R`), which inserts the content of the register `a`.